# 7z returns Error: E_FAIL

Tags: linux, 7-zip

I have made a large backup of files (1,2TB) and i have used 7z on a Debian live system to archive and split it into chunks of 4.5GB. Afaik i did not use a password although i uploaded it all to a oneclick hoster because the data is not sensitive at all. 
Now that i have new HDDs i downloaded my backups and wanted to extract em. From one 3TB WD Red to the other. So there is plenty of space left. But no matter if i Issue "7z e" oder "7z x" or even just "7z l" to my file "backup.7z.001" it always says Error: E_FAIL right away.
Why is that. Google only showed me that this is mainly an error that occours when i dont have enough space left. But i have enough space left. The only partition or drive that is smaller is my system drive, a SSD, with 72GB left. So could there be a temp thing going on?
Iam using debian jessy on a HP Proliant Microserver Gen8. I used these installation cadidates on the NAS "p7zip p7zip-full p7zip-rar". Unfotunately i cant give to much info on what ive used on the live system because my old HDD was about to die and i hand to make the backup at my company because i did not have enough space to compress the files to...
But since i always used those candidates i think i've used the same.

Comment: The same here. Hundreds of files, and only one, 1.6MB cannot be compressed. I removed this problematic file (Codeblocks project *.cbp), and everything works. There are many Codeblock projects but only one causes a problem.